# Do iPhones come with recently used emojis?

Tags: emoji

Do iPhones come with emojis already in the "recently used" area? Like preset in that area?

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, it seems you are interested with the most frequently used emoji. In your keyboard when you toggle the emoji button, the very first tab called "frequently used", shows all the frequently used emoji.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. When you tap the emoji which you use often, it will be shown in your keyboard which called "frequently used".